# What does ***NO_CI*** stand for?

Tags: tfsbuild, checkin

A gated check-in will create a change-set whose name is ended with ***NO_CI***? What is that NO_CI stand for? I can just think of "no check in errors" but it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It stands for **No Continuous Integration**.

Since the check-in is gated, the existing code, plus this check-in, will be built separately and only allowed onwards if the build is successful. So when the gating process actually submits it to source control, there wouldn't be any point for *that* check-in to cause  another (continuous integration) build to occur, since at that point thechangeset is 'known good'.

So this suffix is an instruction to the continuous integration system to the effect of: "When this changeset actually gets committed 'for real', don't automatically fire a continuous integration build on account of it".

Comment: What a sloppy scheme.  Now I have **NO_CI** all over my commits.

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with gated check-ins, it just suppresses triggering of the continuous integration build.

Comment: For what it's worth, the SyncWorkspace action has a property called NoCIOption that can be used to disable the unwanted comment spam.

Comment: Lol, they couldn't find a better place to put this than in the comments field? This is so n00bish , it's almost as bad as MAX_PATH.

Comment: The outputs of our CI build gets checked back into source control in the Drops folder. You can imagine what would happen if this triggers another CI build... But I agree with @ScottStafford- there must be a better way that to stamp NO_CI all over the place.

Comment: Most VCS's do something similar when it comes to linking them to automated builds or CI servers.  I remember using [no-build] in Git commit comments to prevent a build server from building the commit.

Answer (score 16):

NO_CI on a check in indicates "No Continuous Integration" i.e. "please don't start a CI build because of this check in".

Answer (score 2):

This means that there will be no continuous integration (CI) build triggered after this check-in. You will have to modify your XAML file so that the the CI build is triggered after the gated check-in activity is done.

Please refer to the following link for more information on how to customize the XAML file.

http://donovanbrown.com/post/How-to-have-CI-builds-run-after-a-Gated-Build

Answer (score 0):

based on [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1270) you can use `[skip ci]` and the following sentences in commit messages like other DevOps toolkits such as Travis or Circle, ... to skip doing CI pipeline on commits that do not require CI/CD pipelines (like update docs or some chore changes)

- `[skip ci]` or `[ci skip]`
- `skip-checks:true` or `skip-checks:true`
- `[skip azurepipelines]` or `[azurepipelines skip]`
- `[skip azpipelines]` or `[azpipelines skip]`
- `[skip azp]` or `[azp skip]`
- `***NO_CI***`