# Exclude a Working folder from the CI trigger in TFS 2010

Tags: workspace, working-directory

My solution needs additional files from a folder which is not included in the solution folder, so I have set up a 2nd Working folder in the Workspace tab of the Build Definition.

Now the files of this folder get loaded and all links in my solution are fine - the solution builds.

I wrote a custom activity which was generated on the end of the build process new files and check them into the same folder I have likend above (the 2nd Working folder).

However, the files which are check in automatically by the custom activity trigger the whole solution again, and again, and again...

So the real question: how can I exclude a working folder to be triggered on a checkin in Continuous Integration Mode? Cloaking the folder seems not to be the solution because I need the files to build the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have a Continuous Integration build going on. Commiting your changes into TFS with a comment that ends with `***NO_CI***` should prevent builds from re-triggering.
You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829305/what-does-no-ci-stand-for) for some background.