# Is it possible in TFS NOT to trigger a CI build when the content of an active (i.e. NOT cloaked) directory changes?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

My scenario is as follows:

1. Developers check-in SQL changes to directory ClientDB
2. A dedicated build wakes up, extracts the metadata from the checked-in files, processes it and checks the result in into a sibling directory ClientMetadata

(Developers are not allowed to check-in under ClientMetadata)

The annoying side effect, is that because the dedicated build is a CI build it wakes up twice:

1. Once for the changes in ClientDB, which makes it update ClientMetadata
2. Second time, because of its own changes in the ClientMetadata - after all, this directory appears as an Active directory in the Source Settings section of the build:

[image]

Ideally, I would like the ClientMetadata directory to be available in the workspace, but I do not want changes there to trigger the build.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 2nd checkin from the build is done with a checkin comment that has the text `***NO_CI***` at the end, the continuous integration trigger will be suppressed.

It's a hack, but it's how gated checkins work OOTB with TFS.

[What does ***NO_CI*** stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829305/what-does-no-ci-stand-for)

Comment: The Gated Check-In is of no concern here, you probably meant CI build instead. I will test you proposal.

Comment: I know, I was just pointing out that this "feature" is there to support gated checkins, but you can likely utilize it.

Answer (score 0):

Not with XAML build. It's absolutely possible in the build system introduced in TFS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

When you select this trigger (CI)  whenever someone checks in code, the build will run.

Actually check in files to source control during a build pipeline is not a recommended suggestion.

If you don't want to cloaked the ClientMetadata folder and still want this be pulled down on build agent during get source. Please try below workaround:

You could remove the active status for this folder and add a customize activity to only get files from TFS server path($/../../ClientMetadata) to the agent $(BuildDir).